# Why Mathematica shows a blank box?

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to plot the function of Mathematica. But it shows a blank box

```
\[Lambda] = -2.5*I;
e0 = .5;
w = .04;
a1 = sqrt[e0^2 - 4*\[Lambda]^2]*(x + t/(4*\[Lambda]^2 - w^2));
h = e0 - 4*I*\[Lambda]*((e0*Sinh[a1] - 2*I*\[Lambda])/(2*I*\[Lambda]*Sinh[a1] + e0));
Plot3D[Abs[h], {x, -2, 2}, {t, -2, 2}]
```

Comment: Change `sqrt` to `Sqrt` and see if you like the results.  If you are using the Mathematica front-end the blue colouration applied to `sqrt` should have alerted you to the error.